# How to avoid this message in Android

Tags: android

I get the below error message in android.

**Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.example.Recipie/databases/recipedbase.db, table = recipes, query = SELECT DISTINCT title FROM recipes WHERE title="Mysore Pa"
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.(SQLiteCursor.java:210)**

I have added this in my code. But Also i get the above message. Kindly help. :)

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        rDbHelper.close();
    }
```

Comment: should i close all my cursors That I have used?

Comment: Yes - since the message says so ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must close your cursors.

Comment: Should I close it in the same onDestroy() function?

Comment: You should take a look to startManagingCursor and stopManagingCursor at this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor(android.database.Cursor)

Comment: I have closed my cursor and db.. But still im facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I implement moveToFirst() method before fetching the data.
If you still get the error, please make sure that your query get record set.