# How to avoid DatabaseObjectNotClosedException?

Tags: android

01-24 12:17:10.780: ERROR/Database(462): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.test/databases/testdb7.db'

01-24 12:17:10.780: ERROR/Database(462): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the exception. I was calling

```
 db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
```

twice thats why the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

You must close your cursors.

You will find similar question here: [databaseobjectnotclosedexception-how-can-we-avoid-this-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734886/databaseobjectnotclosedexception-how-can-we-avoid-this-exception) also here: [how-to-avoid-this-message-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494233/how-to-avoid-this-message-in-android)

Hope this helps.